# How can I remove an unwanted Chromium installation from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, chromium, malware-removal, unwanted-application

Chromium suddenly installed itself on my computer. It activates on startup. Picking "open file location" from the desktop shortcut shows there's an .exe in \AppData\Local\Chromium\Application. I can't find Chromium in the list under "Apps and features" so I haven't been able to uninstall it. Malwarebytes doesn't detect it as malware.

I think this suddenly appeared after I installed bittorrent clients (qbittorrent and bitcomet) but removing those hasn't gotten rid of the Chromium.

Edit: Settings > Apps > Startup shows Chromium but "Apps & features" does not, so I can't find the normal way of uninstalling.

Edit again: the Chromium in \AppData\Local\Chromium\Application is "chrome.exe" but with the blue Chromium logo, while my proper Google Chrome exe is elsewhere in Program Files.

Comment: Does it installed from online setup executable file?

Comment: I used .exe files to install qbittorrent and bitcomet before Chromium showed up but I never touched a Chromium installer.

Answer (score 1):

Get Chromium the official way and override the previous installation, then uninstall.

Or just delete all the files and registry keys you can find manually.

Comment: I deleted the Chromium folder in AppData and the one I could find using regedit. Task Manager's startup tab now has an entry for "Chrome" with a broken icon. It seems that whatever asks Windows to look for that .exe is still around even though the program itself isn't.

Comment: @shyniknight Perhaps now you should follow the first suggestion, install and uninstall.